# having trouble opening and closing windows in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm really new to python just managing to get my head round it, here is what I have so far.

Basically I'm struggling to switch between I think (mind my coding terminology I'm new to this) i've created a parent window "root=Tk()" and I'm trying to switch to a new area of the program (open up a new window "Class window2")

So I hope you can understand my crap. If you choose to help thanks (Y)

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python       
import sqlite3
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

conn = sqlite3.connect('Logindetails.db')
c = conn.cursor()
column_name = "Username"
attempts = 3

class welcomewindow():

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.lbl = Label(master, text="Please Login")
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.lbl1 = Label(master, text="Username")
        self.lbl1.pack()
        userName=StringVar(None)
        self.userBox = Entry(master, textvariable=userName)
        self.userBox.pack()

        self.lbl2 = Label(master, text="Password")
        self.lbl2.pack()
        passWord=StringVar(None)
        self.passBox = Entry(master, show="*", textvariable=passWord)
        self.passBox.pack()

        self.logoutbut = Button(master, text="Login", width=20, command=self.Loginprocess)
        self.logoutbut.pack(side='bottom', padx=15, pady=15)

        self.exitbut = Button(master, text="Exit", width=20, command=self.exitProgram)
        self.exitbut.pack(side='bottom', padx=15, pady=15)

    def exitProgram(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def Loginprocess(self):
        global attempts

        while attempts < 4 and attempts >= 0:
            print "attempts left = " + str(attempts)
            self.name = self.userBox.get()
            self.password = self.passBox.get()
            if self.password == "" or self.name == "":
                attempts -= 1
            else:
                self.Checkrecord()

    def Checkrecord(self):
        global attempts
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Logindetails.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * FROM Logindetails WHERE Username=? ORDER BY {0}".format(column_name)
        cursor.execute(query, (self.name,))
        for row in cursor:
            if self.name in row and self.password in row:
                self.app = Window2(root)
                welcomewindow.destroy()
            else:
                attempts -= 1
                return

class Window2():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
#       self.title("Cinema Booking System")
#       self.geometry("250x250")












root = Tk()
root.title("Cinema Booking System")
root.geometry("250x250")
cls = welcomewindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames have a zero width by default because there is no reason to show an empty container, so put something in them.  Also you import Tkinter twice.  Choose one or the other.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class WelcomeWindow():

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        ##self.frame = tk.Frame(master)  not used
        self.lbl = tk.Label(master, text="Please Login")
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.lbl1 = tk.Label(master, text="Username")
        self.lbl1.pack()
        userName=tk.StringVar(None)
        self.userBox = tk.Entry(master, textvariable=userName)
        self.userBox.pack()

        self.lbl2 = tk.Label(master, text="Password")
        self.lbl2.pack()
        passWord=tk.StringVar(None)
        self.passBox = tk.Entry(master, show="*", textvariable=passWord)
        self.passBox.pack()

        self.logoutbut = tk.Button(master, text="New Window", width=20,
                     command=self.Checkrecord)
        self.logoutbut.pack(padx=15, pady=15)

        self.exitbut = tk.Button(master, text="Exit", width=20, command=self.exitProgram)
        self.exitbut.pack(padx=15, pady=15)

    def Checkrecord(self):
        self.app = Window2(self.master)

    def exitProgram(self):
        self.master.quit()

class Window2():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.title="Cinema Booking System"
        self.frame.pack(side="bottom")

        tk.Label(self.frame, text="Inside the new frame", bg="orange").pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Cinema Booking System")
root.geometry("250x250")
cls = WelcomeWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you that kinda sorted my problem except all the textboxes and labels from the previous class are still present, how would I remove those? Thanks for the reply really appreciated.

Comment: Never mind sorted it! Thank you so much for getting me on the right tracks.

Comment: Actually, frames have a default width and height of one, not zero.